# How to hold state of label (color, location)

Tags: c#, winforms, label

In Window Forms I have TabControl with 2 tabs. On second tab I add dynamically in for loop labels from xml file based on cords in xml file. When I click on whichever label shows up new Form with three buttons (Important, Total, Address). When I choose for example important label must change color on Orange (I can handle that). My problem is how to save state (color, location) of these label which was clicked. I need that, because state of these labels which was clicked go to database. I have no idea how to save or hold it this state.

Comment: What is it needed for? Do you want to set the state after the application is restarted?

Comment: I need that:
Label  --- click --->  Form shows up ----> Button --- click ---> change color of label -- (to this place no problems) --> save (label color & label location) in temp array, list or something else. Do you understand everything or show it in code?

Comment: I understand it until this point. What I don't understand is, when will you load that data. What happens to the XML?

Comment: `var something = label.something`?

Comment: XML ---> Load XML ---> Read XML by XMLDocument & XMLNode --->
Get location cords & text from XML ---> Set Label in for loop --->
Click on created dynamically label ---> Form shows up --->
Click on ex. "important button" ---> change clicked Label color to RED --->
Save in temporary place clicked label color and location where is placed in TabPage --->
Click button "Send to Database" ---> Only labels which are in temporary place are sending to the database ---> The End ;)

XML file is readonly

Comment: but label has label.something? what is something, I need to store clicked label color and location. After label click I have method
private void labelclicked(object sender, eventargs e) {
Label label = sender as Label;
}
That I working on clicked label

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your labes referrable in code. For example by giving them unique names once you create them from XML, like "lblNode141".

Next, if you say, they "go to database" you should have a place there where you can store that information. For example, you could create a table like this:

```
LabelName   | X | Y |  Color
-----------------------------
lblNode141  | 20| 30| #577ae4
lblNode142  | 20| 60| #ff8000
lblNode143  | 20| 90| #14bfb2
```

Now, the next time you create your labels from the same XML, you can retrieve the chosen values from the database. Just query over the name, given that it is unique. You may need to extend those names to get them really unique, I don't have enough information about that.

Note, this is ONE possible solution - depending on what you really want to achieve, this might not perfectly fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
In for loop I've add each one label to List, and in other Button I've check in foreach which label has color and location I needed.